Закрывается игра при переходе на другую сцену в Godot 4
При переходе на другую сцену, она появляется на 1 секунду и игра сразу закрывается.
Код кнопки:
extends Button


func _on_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://scenes/settings.tscn")


Когда я в Godot 4.2.2 с помощью этого кода перехожу на пустую сцену settings.tscn, ничего нигде не закрывается. То есть по приведённой в вопросе информации проблема не воспроизводится
